# Fetch unicode string key/value using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a unicode string called

```
get_secret_value_response =  {u'Name':....u'SecretString':u'{"username": "username", "password": "password"}'
```

I would like to fetch the username and password.
however, when I tried accessing using as dict for python it's saying

```
if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
        secret = get_secret_value_response["SecretString"]
    print(secret.keys())
    'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: It seems like you are calling keys for the unicode string instead of the dict. get_secret_value_response["SecretString"]["username"] should work

Comment: Where is the secret_username defined?

Comment: I have edited the question @AmartyaGaur and `get_secret_value_response["SecretString"]["username"]` shows me `string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Your dictionary declaration is not correct. The braces are not balanced

Answer (score 1):

your `get_secret_value_response["SecretString"]` returns a str.
You have to convert it to a json/dict.

```
import json

if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
    secret = json.loads(get_secret_value_response["SecretString"])
    print(secret.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is causing by `'SecretString'` is a string and it's treated as a dictionary.
To convert it to a dictionary you can use `literal_eval` method like

```
from ast import literal_eval

get_secret_value_response = {u'SecretString':u'{"username": "username", "password": "password"}'}
if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
    secret = literal_eval(get_secret_value_response["SecretString"])

print(secret.keys())
```

This will output

```
dict_keys(['username', 'password'])
```

The most important thing here that the `secret` variable will be converted to a dictionary and you will be able to use it by keys values pairs.